# How can I stop org-mode treating a number followed by a full stop as a bullet point?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, fill-paragraph

I'm using org-mode to write some documentation. After changing some wording, `fill-paragraph` has arranged things so there's a number followed by a full stop at the start of a line. Like this:

```
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
64. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

Blah blah blah blah blah.
```

When I export to HTML, org-mode then makes an ordered list item of that one line, making things look a mess. Is there anything I can do to indicate that a particular number followed by a full stop should never be treated as a list item?

I use the list behaviour elsewhere, so I don't want to globally disable it.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but you could use soft-wrapping (`visual-line-mode` built-in, `visual-fill-column-mode` 3rd party) instead of hard-wrapping by `fill-paragraph`. Would it break other things for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customize `org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator`.

While generally, customizing what org considers or doesn't consider a list item is somewhat tricky, the option provides exactly what you need. You have three options:

- 1. this is an item,
- 2) this is an item, or
- 3 both 1. and 2) are items.

[Note that stackexchange also seems to have a problem interpreting this.]

Select 2, and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks! Strange it doesn't allow more customization - both sequences strike me as quite likely to occur in text naturally. Something like "1/ " would make more sense, to my eyes. But now I know of the variable, I can have a look and maybe try to fix that myself...

Comment: Start with the variable `org-list-full-item-re` and the function `org-item-re`. Then you'd have to experiment and see if it is hardcoded somewhere else.

Comment: Also `org-element--set-regexps` Then run `org-element-update-syntax`

Answer (score 11):

This has been a problem for me when creating documents in Danish, where "3rd quarter" is "3. kvartal".   The solution I use in such situations is to replace the space after the dot by a non-breaking space by typing `C-q 240`.  This is appropriate in such situations where the dot is not an end of sentence character and could perhaps be used as a work around in your situation.