# Exporting a file from ORG MODE automatically changes my numbering

Tags: org-mode

I have several ORG files which I wish to export to HTML or ODT from emacs. These files have specific numbering. However when I export them the numbers are automatically adjusted. For example in the file I would have the following numbers:

3. ויאמר = ordered.
4. ילדים - the object of ויביאם (verse 3).
5. לחסד ולרחמים - ל in both instances marks a second object.

After export, these numbers appears as 1. 2. 3.

How can I change this?

Comment: http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html see the second bullet point here, i.e. you would need to start the list with `[@3]`.

Comment: Thank you. This not actually a list but a series of comments on verses in a text. I would like to instruct emacs **not** to treat these numbers as a list.

Comment: This has been asked already, but it's hard to find: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/how-can-i-stop-org-mode-treating-a-number-followed-by-a-full-stop-as-a-bullet-po . Other than the options suggested in that answer: what you are doing looks like a footnote to me, wouldn't that be a more proper format for it?