# How to org-export literal list?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have several strings in my org file, which look like as follows:

5. something
6. something else

When I org-export this file to html, these strings are automatically converted to lists, starting with 1. How to prevent that and export literal strings? Better with some specific #+OPTION or something like that. And how to disable offsets and padding for such strings?

Comment: It's not only html. That's org mode syntax for lists, probably from `org-item-re`. Sometimes I can't find ways to escape the org mode syntax :( but maybe you can mess with `org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator` if you don't use lists anywhere else in the file.

Comment: Is it possible to change `org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator` just for one particulat file?

Comment: Ah, as suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10422/14438) inserting a non-breaking space after number and a dot works fine. It can be done with `C-x 8 SPC`. But it is also dirty thing. Would be better to customize `org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator` in `#+STARTUP` or in `#+OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export literal text you'll need to use the [literal example](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html) syntax.

e.g.

- Original text

  ```
  5. something
  6. something else
  ```
- Literal Example

  ```
  #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
   5. something
   6. something else
  #+END_EXAMPLE
  ```

  Exports to HTML as `PRE` tags

  ```
      <pre class="example">
      5. something
      6. something else
      </pre>
  ```

An Alternative solution using [org entities](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) and [replace-regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html)

e.g.

- Original text

  ```
  5. something
  6. something else
  ```
- Entities Example

  ```
  \nbsp5. something
  \nbsp6. something else
  ```

  Exports to HTML as `&nbsp;`

  ```
  &nbsp;5. something
  &nbsp;6. something else
  ```

  I used following command to do the search & replace:

  <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>replace-regexp</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>([0-9]+. )</kbd><kbd>\nbsp\1</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

---

Tested using

> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13)
>   org-mode: 9.0

Comment: Except you now get the formatting for examples.  You could trick the CSS to change it, but you can't do that if you also want to use real examples.

Comment: @JeanPierre - Good point!! I'll update my answer to include a workaround that doesn't export as `pre` tags but uses [org entities](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) instead.