# Non-breaking space in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, formatting

In LaTeX one can use `~` to produce a non-breaking space. Is there an analogue in org-mode?

Comment: do you mean for exporting to latex? [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16176740/8544157)

Comment: also just found [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10422/17548) by @Andrew Swann . Insert a nbsp with `C-q 240`

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this?

Comment: I'm exporting a document to LaTeX, and the calling of a reference break at the end of line... interpret the following "... as shown in Ref. [3]" -> "... as shown in Ref. \n [3]". But "... as shown in Ref.\nbsp[3]" -> "... as shown in \n Ref. [3]". i.e. it forces the word Ref. to stay together with the calling [3].

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this problem myself while writing up some reports. Beyond the answer provided by @Andrew Swann (and mentioned by @manandearth above), according to the manual (https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Symbols.html), you can insert a non-breaking-space using the `\nbsp{}` LaTeX command.